How to output data from an execution of a SSM Document
I´m working on a AWS SSM Document that accepts two parameters as inputs and outputs a string (or something likewise). The purpouse of this document is to check if a service, passed by parameter input, is running on an EC2 instance, also passed by parameter input. It consists of two parts, one designed to work on windows, the other designed to work on linux.
This document is being executed by a lambda with python code that runs the document providing it with an instance_ID and a service_Name.
I have already worked out the input parameters and how to work with them, but I haven´t found a way to extract a variable string from the execution (the service status basically).
Is there a way to get said variable string in the response from the send_command() function of boto3?
Or any other way? I´m open to redo everything as this is my first hand-on experience with all of this technologies.
Beforehand, thanks for your time and attention.
Note: I am completely new in AWS and powershell.
This is the SSM Document code that if written so far:
description: 'Install status checker scripts with custom dimension'
mainSteps:
- action: aws:runPowerShellScript
  inputs:
    runCommand:

    - '$serviceName={{serviceName}}'
    - '$instanceId={{instanceId}}'
    - ''
    - '# Check if a service name was provided'
    - 'param([string]$serviceName,[string]$instanceId)'
    - 'if (-not $serviceName) {'
    - '    Write-Host "Usage -> check_service_windows.ps1 -serviceName <service-name>"'
    - '    exit'    
    - '}'
    - 'if (-not $instanceId) {'
    - '    Write-Host "Usage -> check_service_windows.ps1 -serviceName <service-name> -instanceId <InstanceID>"'
    - '    exit'    
    - '}'
    - '# Check the status of the service'
    - '$service = Get-Service -Name $serviceName'
    - '# Determine the metric value based on the service status'
    - '$metricValue = if ($service.Status -eq "Running") { 0 } else { 1 }'
    - '# Display the service status'
    - 'Write-Host "{\"checked\": \"yes\", \"metricValue\": $metricValue}"'
 
    timeoutSeconds: 7200
  name: Windows
  outputs:
  - Name: Status
    Selector: $
    Type: String
  precondition:
    StringEquals:
    - platformType
    - Windows

- action: aws:runShellScript
  inputs:
    runCommand:
    - 'export service_name={{serviceName}}'
    - 'export instance_id={{instanceId}}'
    - '# Check if a service name was provided'
    - 'if [ -z "$service_name" ]; then'
    - '    echo "Usage: $0 <service-name>"'
    - '    exit 1'
    - 'fi'
    - 'if [ -z "$instance_id" ]; then'
    - '    echo "Usage: $0 $1 <instance-id>"'
    - '    exit 1'
    - 'fi'
    - ''
    - '# Function to check service status with systemctl'
    - 'check_with_systemctl() {'
    - '    status=$(systemctl is-active "$service_name")'
    - '    case "$status" in'
    - '        active)'
    - '            echo "{\"checked\": \"yes\", \"metricValue\": 0}"'
    - '            echo "Service $service_name is running."'
    - '            ;;'
    - '        *)'
    - '            echo "{\"checked\": \"yes\", \"metricValue\": 1}"'
    - '            echo "Service $service_name is not running."'
    - '            ;;'
    - '    esac'
    - '}'
    - ''
    - '# Function to check service status with service command for SysVinit'
    - 'check_with_service() {'
    - '    if service "$service_name" status > /dev/null; then'
    - '        echo "{\"checked\": \"yes\", \"metricValue\": 0}"'
    - '        echo "Service $service_name is running."'
    - '    else'
    - '        echo "{\"checked\": \"yes\", \"metricValue\": 1}"'
    - '        echo "Service $service_name is not running or not installed."'
    - '    fi'
    - '}'
    - ''
    - '# Determine if the system uses systemd'
    - 'if pidof systemd > /dev/null; then'
    - '    check_with_systemctl'
    - 'else'
    - '    check_with_service'
    - 'fi'
    timeoutSeconds: 7200
  name: Linux
  outputs:
  - Name: Status
    Selector: $
    Type: String
  precondition:
    StringEquals:
    - platformType
    - Linux

parameters:
  serviceName:
    type: String
  instanceId:
    type: String

schemaVersion: '2.2'

And here is the lambda code that executes the document:
import boto3

def run_script_per_service(tag_key):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
    ssm = boto3.client('ssm')

    responseEC2 = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=[
    {'Name': 'tag-key', 'Values': [tag_key]},
    {'Name': 'tag:Group', 'Values': ['Development']}
    ])
    
    for reservation in responseEC2['Reservations']:
        for instance in reservation['Instances']:
            if (instance['State']['Name'] == 'running'):
                instanceID = instance['InstanceId']
                print("Comenzando checkeo de la instancia " + instanceID + "...")
                for tag in instance['Tags']:
                    if tag['Key'] == tag_key:
                        tag_value = tag['Value']
                        service_list = tag_value.split(",")
                        for service in service_list:
                            print("Comenzando checkeo del servicio " + service + "...")
                            responseSSM = ssm.send_command(
                                InstanceIds=[
                                    instanceID,
                                ],
                                DocumentName='SSM-Service_Status_Monitoring-Installer',
                                Parameters={
                                    'serviceName': [
                                        f"\"{service}\""
                                    ],
                                    'instanceId': [
                                        f"\"{instanceID}\""
                                    ]
                                }
                            )
                            print(responseSSM)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    tag_key = 'Services'
    run_script_per_service(tag_key)


Apparently you can specify in the YAML code of the SSM Document a step to output variables:
Here is the chunk of code necessary
´´´
outputs:

Name: Status
Selector: "$.stdout"
Type: String


